# Is there a shorter way to check to allow all video formats?

Tags: javascript, jquery, case

In my case statement it checks for file extensions for some video formats, but what I want to know is that except creating a huge list to allow only these video formats below, is there a short way to code to allow only all video formats?

Below is cast statement:

```
function videoValidation(videouploadform) {

    var val = $(videouploadform).find(".fileVideo").val();
    switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'mpg':
        case 'mov': 
        case 'wmv':
        case 'rm':
        case '3g2':
        case '3gp':
             return true;

        case '':
            $(videouploadform).find(".fileVideo").val();
            alert("To upload an video, please select an Video File");
            return false;

        default:
            alert("To upload an video, please select a valild file extension.");
            return false;

    }

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by checking mimetype of files, almost every video format mimetype started with video/ e.g in case of mp4 video (video/mp4)

You can check mime type of files via

```
var mimetype = document.getElementById('file').files[0].type;
var reg = /video/;
if (reg.test(mimetype) {
    // valid video format
} else {
    // not valid video format
}
```

Comment: where do I put this in code above? Also what is mimetype for audio and images?

Comment: You should use the variable mimetype and check indexOf("video"), if it returns 0, then you're good, -1 and it didn't find the string "video" in the mime type.

Comment: complete list of mimetypes here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full, video related mimetypes http://www.codingcereal.com/2011/10/an-array-of-45-video-mime-types/

Comment: Hi, thanks, do you know what mimetypes is for images and audio? is it /images/ for Images and /audio/ for Audio?

Comment: This is just wrong. If I rename a text file and call it video.mov, according to your validation it's now a video in that format. When you let the user choose a file to upload filter on extension for convenience, the only way to know if it's valid video file, is to try and play it on a specific system, and just because it has a specific extension doesn't even start to mean that will work.

Comment: @user1324106 yes for images mimetype started with images/ and for audio audio/ in most of cases. may be differ in some rare cases

Comment: @TonyHopkinson yes, you must validate video or any file via server side scripting in order to make sure video is valid 100%, as i encounter virus attach few times on my websites. via asp.net i know how to check mimetype via stream classes.

Comment: My apologies @Muhammad, was meant to be a comment on teh question, not your answer